# Executing a Command Getting OS version prints two times while using script, but it actually prints one time while executing manual

Tags: bash

I executed below command in  RHEL6.10 
'''
./tqreclist -s server -t HINV.Summary | awk -F, '{print $4}'
'''
when I execute it manually, I am getting OS version printed in my screen, either Linux or Windows.

But When I execute the same command in bash script, I am getting the same version printed twice, like Linux Linux, Windows Windows.

I thought something bad in my code, So I examined it properly, Immediately after executing the above command, I noticed it prints duplicate value in screen so I changed from awk to cut, but I am getting the same results.
Could someone please help me what would be wrong?

```
a=$(./tqreclist -s server -t HINV.Summary | awk -F, '{print $4}')

echo $a
```

I expect it should print actual value, rather then, it is now printing two value, which is duplicate of one.

Comment: Is `HINV.summary` a multi-line file?

Comment: tqreclist is a command used to fetch data from database, HINV.Summary is one of the table , which stores inventory details of the server, yes, it's multiline.

Comment: If the file it multiline, do you just wish to look at the first line to find the OS version?  Or for better paste a few lines of the file here for us to have an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your problem as follows, but it works correctly for me:

```
$ a=$(echo "1,2,3,4,5,6,7" | awk -F, '{print $4}')
$ echo $a
4
```

If you try a test like this yourself and it works correctly, then the issue is most likely with the "tqreclist" file.

Comment: The file should be the culprit here. Perhaps do `wc -l file`

Comment: I think so too. I don't have his file to test with.

Comment: @DovRine,sjsam - tqreclist is command, which calls the teamquest database, teamquest is a monitoring tool, HINV.Summary is the table which stores information of server inventory. When I execute the command from command line, it works perfectly. But When I execute it in script, it print double times, one is original another one is duplicate.

Comment: @RafiqShaikh, Maybe the first one is the output from tqreclist itself. Maybe try ending the parens before the pipe to awk and then wrapping the whole thing in another $().